# How to limit logon time access for groups

Tags: linux, openldap, access-control-list, pam

I have to limit logon time access for some users. I have googled and found it is possible with pam modules and time.conf.

My question is: is it possible to do the same but with groups so, instead of dealing with users, just gather these users and set limited logon time to this group?

I am using an ldap server with centos7.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this can be accomplished with some work with a combination of `pam_listfile` and `pam_time`. You will have to fill in the details but here is the skeleton in your `pam.conf`

```
auth [success=1 default=ok] pam_listfile.so item=group sense=deny file=/path/to/restricted/groups onerr=fail
account required pam_time.so ...
```

The `success=1` means, if this module returns success, then skip the next 1 module. I.e. if the user is not in any of the denied groups, don't run pam_time.so, otherwise do run it.