# Linux pam_time with groups

Tags: linux, security, pam, restrictions

How do I allow `/etc/security/time.conf` to be able to restrict groups instead of users?

It works flawlessly with users but not with groups. I need to have multiple groups in my case.

Comment: Does this answer your question?   https://serverfault.com/questions/880797/how-to-limit-logon-time-access-for-groups

Comment: No it doesn't, as he is not explaining what should be replacing "user" line  in /etc/security/time.conf file.